# Harry Potter fanfic in which Snape adopts Harry

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I read it such a long time ago and I loved it, and now I want to re-read it but, I can't remember where it was posted.

I remember that Harry calls Snape's mom and it contains Tom Riddle/Severus Snape. I can't remember but it could also have Harry in a wheelchair with some kind of disability.